# Is a Func<T> always the same object?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Basically, if I do something like this ...

```
class Bla
  T Run(Func<T> myFun)
    return myFun()

  void SomeMethod()
    Run( () => whatever() )
```

and then myFun always the same object, or a new object each time? Or formulated in a slightly different manner ... if I would put a lock on it, would it prevent parallel execution?

Comment: Are you asking if `() => whatever()` creates a new delegate object each time?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: yes.

Comment: If you don't know how an object got created then you can *never* be sure that the object is suitable to store the lock state.  True for GetType(), true for *this*, double-true for a method argument, triple-true for a delegate object.  Always, *always* create your own object with `new object()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
() => whatever()
```

creates a new delegate object every time.

That means that if two threads both call `SomeMethod` at the same time, then each of them will construct their own delegate and putting a lock inside `Run` will not ensure only one thread can run the delegate passed to its `Run`.

[You can test this in this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EfOaHV).

Comment: Damn, thought as much, but was hoping I was wrong. Also neat site there, didn't know that one.